# Update Eclipse project with local repository changes push

Tags: git, egit

I have a local GIT repository which is shared for a co-worker to pull from/push to it. Now he has done his first push, but I'm unable to update my Eclipse project with his changes. In fact his changes appear like deletions to me, that is, Synchronize shows as me having deleted his recently pushed files:

[image]

**Overwrite** throws an error:

```
An internal error occurred during: "Overwriting 3 resources.".
Attempted to beginRule: F/Core/src/com/blablabla/android/core, does not match outer scope rule: F/Core/src/com/blablabla/android/core/db
```

**Merge** says there are no changes to merge.

Comment: Comments on the downvoting are welcome :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is due to [this bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=362219) (I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS btw, so the bug applies for Linux as well as WXP)

To solve this, I just had to create the missing directories (in my example, the core/db package -directory- was not created) and then **Overwrite** will work correctly.